# Surveymonkey OAuth2.0 error Error: Missing required parameter(s): client_secret

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh-token, surveymonkey, redirect-uri

I'm trying to generate the refresh token via Postman for Surveymonkey

I'm passing the client_id and client_secret but still getting the error Error: Missing required parameter(s): client_secret

Also, what would I use as the redirect URL on the settings page on SurveyMonkey for my APP that is created?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out , in the client_secret you have to provide client_secret value (this will only show at the time when you register the app) not the client_secret id , please cross check and retry again .

hope this help, please let us know if you have any query .

Thanks